# Crystal Reports Printing to Different Printers

Tags: crystal-reports

SAP Crystal Reports Version 14.1.1.1036.

I have setup two printers on my server, both printers are to the same printer but different trays. Different paper in each tray, we'll call them PrinterA and PrinterB. I am trying to print a two page report to the two printers, basically page 1 going to PrinterA and page 2 going to PrinterB. There are hundreds and thousands of these to print. I've created a main report page, added two subreports, one subreport on page 1 and the other subreport on page 2; then tried to set different printers to each subreport or page. Every time I go back to the main page, the last saved printer is selected for the main and each subreport. I was hoping that the printer I setup for each subreport would be used, but this is not the case. I know this can probably be achieved via 3rd party tools (Visual Cut maybe??), but is there any way to do this natively in Crystal Reports?  And we do need the pages matched up in one output tray, otherwise we would just setup two jobs and print all page 1s to one printer and all page 2s to another printer. Thanks.

Comment: Don think you can do it natively in CR. However might be worth try setting a specfic page setting for a subreport based on the tray and then try it. May be page layout forces it to go to the tray it needs to rather than default.

Comment: aMazing, that's exactly what I had thought and tried. Unfortunately the entire page, including subreports, appear to reflect the last saved or configured printer.

Answer (score 0):

Visual CUT can indeed do this using one of two different methods. See [this](http://www.milletsoftware.com/Visual_CUT_User_Manual/#Printing%20PDF%20Files%20To%20Multiple%20Printer%20Trays) in the user manual. 
The process starts with automating the export to PDF and then splitting the printing of the PDF across the desired printer trays.